# Hover 2 divs same time

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i have a column that is a button, and im trying to make it change the background color and his elements color, but im having some trouble in changing one of the elements that is a icon from awesome fonts, above i leave my code:

html:

```
<a href="">
<div class="col-xs-4 bordered-right btn-dashboard">
<p class=""><strong>TITLE</strong></p>
     <h4><i  class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i></h4>
        <p><small>Subt Title</small></p>
</div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.col-xs-4.btn-dashboard:hover {
    background-color: #35b34c;
    color: white;
}

.col-xs-4.btn-dashboard.fa-wheelchair:hover{
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Add a space here: `.col-xs-4.btn-dashboard .fa-wheelchair:hover`

Comment: He changes the color of the icon but only if i hover in the icon, but not in the element that is being wraped  (col-xs.btn..)

Comment: Then this is appropriate `.col-xs-4.btn-dashboard:hover .fa-wheelchair`, ... oh I just saw there's an answer already ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change `.col-xs-4.btn-dashboard.fa-wheelchair:hover` to `.col-xs-4.btn-dashboard:hover .fa-wheelchair`.

Comment: On a side note. Remove the class col-xs-4 from the selector. If you later decide that you want the button to be a different size, you will break the selector.

Comment: @MônicaR. Glad it's working! I agree with Andreas, the `.col-xs-4` should probably be removed from the selectors. Please make sure you mark any of the answers as correct to help people in the future!  :)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `.col-xs-4` and `.fa-wheelchair` from your CSS rules. What happens if you decide to use `.col-xs-3` instead or another `.fa-something-else` icon? You'll have to update the CSS each and every time you make such changes. I would instead do:

```
.btn-dashboard:hover {
    background-color: #35b34c;
    color: white;
}

.btn-dashboard:hover h4 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

If you only want to change the color of the `font-awesome` icon in the `h4` you can do this instead:

```
.btn-dashboard:hover h4 i { /* or i.fa */
    color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a space between your CSS classes and you should put the hover to the div, so the icon is shown white, when die mouse is hovering over the div and not only over the icon (I assume this is your intention).

```css
.col-xs-4.btn-dashboard:hover {
    background-color: #35b34c;
    color: white;
}

.col-xs-4.btn-dashboard:hover .fa-wheelchair{
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<a href="">
<div class="col-xs-4 bordered-right btn-dashboard">
<p class=""><strong>TITLE</strong></p>
     <h4><i  class="fa fa-wheelchair">ICON</i></h4>
        <p><small>Subt Title</small></p>
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector chain is wrong (missing a space) - try -

> .col-xs-4.btn-dashboard .fa.fa-wheelchair

Your CSS is looking for an element with ALL of those classes - as opposed to child elements of something with one class.